# Add css class jQuery multiple rows if it has an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following layout, This is just an example and it changes from page to page.

What i need to do is add 2 different CSS classes to each of the divs that has the class already vertical padding and MUST HAVE AN ID.

This is so that I can make the background-colors be in sync, grey, white, grey white for each of the divs that has an ID. If they do not have an ID they shouldnt have a class white or grey assigned: As the amount of divs with an ID changes from page to page I need some type of jQuery function to programatically add white and grey background for odd or even or ones yes and one row no. But the DIV's MUST HAVE already and ID.

for example:

```css
.grey-bg {
    background-color: grey;
}

.white-bg {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<article id="55" class="post-55">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="row-main">
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="welcome">1</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="welcome-2">2</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding">3</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding">4</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding"id="hello">5</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="welcome">6</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding">8</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding">9</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="welcome-4">7</div>
            <div class="fl-row vertical-padding"id="hello">10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Also note that ID's cannot start with **numbers** and must be **unique**.

Comment: loop throug all div and search if it has using div[i].innerHTML.includes('id')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with css by using `[id]` with `:nth-of-type()`:

```css
.vertical-padding[id] {
  color: white;
}

.vertical-padding[id]:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: grey;
}

.vertical-padding[id]:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="row-main">
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="welcome">1</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="welcome-2">2</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding">3</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding">4</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding"id="hello">5</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="welcome">6</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding">8</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding">9</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="welcome-4">7</div>
    <div class="fl-row vertical-padding" id="hello">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didnt know i could use CSS to do that thanks for pointing out, its working fine on y our code snippet however on my actual site it doesnt quite work as some rows are still showing 2 white colors or 2 grey colors but i will accept your answer and debug myself thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var a= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var n= 1;
    for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++){
    {
       if(a[i].innerHTML.includes('id'))
       {
          if(n%2==0){
            //1st color
           }
          else{
          // 2nd color
          }
        n++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: hi this is also good but after it loops trough all with ID's how do you determine odd and even?

Comment: initialize a variable and increment inside if loop

Comment: sorry could you elaborate on that inside the if statement i make a variable for odd and even? then assign it?

Comment: Hello thanks for that, then i would use the following to add the class right?
document.getElementsByTagName('vertical-padding').classList.add('white-bg');

Comment: Yes , add the class name to div